# Kafka: Error serializing Avro message with Schema Registry

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro

I'm trying to send `ProducerRecord`s of my custom type to Kafka, but I'm getting the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported Avro type. Supported types are null, Boolean, Integer, Long, Float, Double, String, byte[] and IndexedRecord
```

I set up schema in Schema:
GET

```
http://localhost:8081/subjects/documentCreations-key/versions/3
```

Response:

```
{
"subject": "documentCreations-key",
"version": 3,
"id": 1,
"schema": "\"string\""}
```

GET

```
http://localhost:8081/subjects/documentCreations-value/versions/4
```

Response

```
{
"subject": "documentCreations-value",
"version": 4,
"id": 23,
"schema": "{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"Document\",\"namespace\":\"com.bade\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"path\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"
```

}

Here is my Scala class:

```
class Document(val name: java.lang.String,
               val title: java.lang.String,
               val path: java.lang.String)
```

And the part with KafkaProducer:

```
class MyKafkaProducer {

  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  props.put("key.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer")
  props.put("value.serializer", "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer")
  props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://localhost:8081")

  private val producer = new KafkaProducer[java.lang.String, Document](props)

  def sendCreateDocumentMessage(document: Document): RecordMetadata = {

    val documentRecord = new ProducerRecord[java.lang.String, Document](SharedConfig
      .documentCreationsTopic,
      document.name, document)

    producer.send(documentRecord).get()
  }
```

What am I missing? I see that I can implement SpecificRecord for my class, but  I didn't see that as necessary in book/tutorials that I've been reading.
Thanks!

EDITED: Fixed class name

Comment: You show `MoreDocument`, but you're sending `Document`...

Comment: edited, sorry. I changed the naming so to not interfere with business logic.

Comment: So, what part of this code is converting your case class to Avro?

Comment: You might want to check out this library https://github.com/ovotech/kafka-serialization/blob/master/README.md#avro-example

Comment: I thought KafkaAvroSerializer does that, maybe with reflection and by providing the type in schema. Ok, I'll check it, thanks.

Comment: I've only been using Java with AVDL generated classes, but I believe it's using the standard Java serializer the way you've written it

Comment: This link doesn't use Confluent's KafkaAvroSerializer. Does that mean you didn't use it at all?

Comment: Yes, it does... https://github.com/ovotech/kafka-serialization/blob/master/avro4s/src/main/scala/com/ovoenergy/kafka/serialization/avro4s/Avro4sSerialization.scala#L11  You would have to add this library to your dependencies. Its a *wrapper* around the confluent serializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. Apparently, (de)serialization is not done automatically (via reflection or something), but you have to generate the class from avro schema file. Posting my `pom.xml` if it will be helpful to someone:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>

    <plugins>

        <!--force java 8-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schema</goal>
                        <goal>protocol</goal>
                        <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDirectory>src/main/avro
                        </sourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>

                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!--force discovery of generated classes-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>target/generated-sources/avro</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>confluent</id>
        <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <kafka.version>1.0.0</kafka.version>
    <confluent.version>4.0.0</confluent.version>
    <avro.version>1.8.2</avro.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
        <version>${confluent.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>${avro.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${avro.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

I build it with following mvn commands:

```
mvn clean:clean avro:schema compiler:compile scala:compile jar:jar
```

Comment: I am facing the same error while producing a record. Does it matter that I have removed `protocol` and `idl-protocol` goals from pom since I do not have avdl or avpr files. The java classes gets generated alright without them. The generated POJO already implements `SpecificRecord`